# bootstrap column not aligned

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to list 3 column in a row I have added bootstrap for responsive.but I display only one column in single row.what I did wrong in my code.I have added row.I have created carousel which I want to display 3 column.but it shows only one column

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="suggested_content" class="row">
<div class="view view-suggested-content view-id-suggested_content view-display-id-block suggested-content view-dom-id-1fc7487dcb5039856b57c03c2939611b col-md-12">
        
  
    <h2>Suggested Content</h2>

       <!-- col-md-1 col-sm-1-->
    <div class="view-content carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div id="previous_arrow" class=""><span><img src="/test/sites/default/files/arrow-prev.png"></span></div>
<div id="views-bootstrap-grid-1" class="views-bootstrap-grid-plugin-style carousel-inner">
           <div class="item active">
              <div class="responsive-grid-1 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="suggestedContent">
 <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/_MG_7359_5.JPG?itok=3ublCCMm" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Blog</div>
 <div class="sug-ontent">
  <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">test content 2</span></div>
  <div class="suggested-url">
       <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Know More</a> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
            </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item ">
               <div class="responsive-grid-2 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="suggestedContent">
 <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/_MG_7277_2.JPG?itok=g-BQKDH3" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Blog</div>
 <div class="sug-ontent">
  <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">test content 1</span></div>
  <div class="suggested-url">
       <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Know More</a> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
                 <div class="responsive-grid-3 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="suggestedContent">
 <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/Manpower%20Firm.jpg?itok=_bYBf1j1" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Case Study</div>
 <div class="sug-ontent">
  <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">A Manpower Firm engages with Aspire to Align their Business Process with Oracle...</span></div>
  <div class="suggested-url">
       <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
          </div>
    </div>
                <div class="item ">
                   <div class="responsive-grid-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="suggestedContent">
 <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/Manpower%20Firm.jpg?itok=_bYBf1j1" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Case Study</div>
 <div class="sug-ontent">
  <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">A Manpower Firm engages with Aspire to Align their Business Process with Oracle...</span></div>
  <div class="suggested-url">
       <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
          </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <div class="responsive-grid-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="suggestedContent">
 <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/Seasonal%20Merchandise.jpg?itok=nBDMdUIz" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Article</div>
 <div class="sug-ontent">
  <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">Seasonal Merchandise Planning to focus on Customer Centricity and Inventory...</span></div>
  <div class="suggested-url">
       <a href="http://localhost/articles/customer-centricity-merchandise-planning-and-inventory-optimization/" target="_blank">Read More</a> 
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
          </div>
                </div>
                </div>
  <div id="next_arrow" class=""><span><img src="/test/sites/default/files/arrow-next.png"></span></div>   <!-- col-md-1 col-sm-1-->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
  
  
  
  
  
</div></div>

  </div>
```

Comment: In a carousel, you want to display three columns?

Comment: ya 3 column in carousel

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `col-xs-12` class to show the single `column` in a line.

So I have edited you `code`.

If you follow my code, you will have single element/column in `one` line.

HTML:

```
<div id="suggested_content" class="row">
<div class="view view-suggested-content view-id-suggested_content view-display-id-block suggested-content view-dom-id-1fc7487dcb5039856b57c03c2939611b col-md-12">
    <h2>Suggested Content</h2>
    <!-- col-md-1 col-sm-1-->
    <div class="view-content carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div id="previous_arrow" class=""><span><img src="/test/sites/default/files/arrow-prev.png"></span></div>
        <div id="views-bootstrap-grid-1" class="views-bootstrap-grid-plugin-style carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="responsive-grid-1 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="suggestedContent">
                        <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/_MG_7359_5.JPG?itok=3ublCCMm" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Blog</div>
                        <div class="sug-ontent">
                            <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">test content 2</span></div>
                            <div class="suggested-url">
                                <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Know More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <div class="responsive-grid-2 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="suggestedContent">
                        <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/_MG_7277_2.JPG?itok=g-BQKDH3" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Blog</div>
                        <div class="sug-ontent">
                            <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">test content 1</span></div>
                            <div class="suggested-url">
                                <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Know More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <div class="responsive-grid-3 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="suggestedContent">
                        <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/Manpower%20Firm.jpg?itok=_bYBf1j1" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div>    <div class="perspective-title">Case Study</div>
                        <div class="sug-ontent">
                            <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">A Manpower Firm engages with Aspire to Align their Business Process with Oracle...</span></div>
                            <div class="suggested-url">
                                <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <div class="responsive-grid-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="suggestedContent">
                        <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/Manpower%20Firm.jpg?itok=_bYBf1j1" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div>    <div class="perspective-title">Case Study</div>
                        <div class="sug-ontent">
                            <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">A Manpower Firm engages with Aspire to Align their Business Process with Oracle...</span></div>
                            <div class="suggested-url">
                                <a href="http://localhost/casestudies/A%20Manpower%20Firm%20engages%20with%20Aspire%20to%20Align%20their%20Business%20Process%20with%20Oracle%20Cloud%20Solutions.pdf" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="responsive-grid-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="suggestedContent">
                        <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/inner_perspective/public/Seasonal%20Merchandise.jpg?itok=nBDMdUIz" width="320" height="220" alt=""></div> <div class="perspective-title">Article</div>
                        <div class="sug-ontent">
                            <div class="suggested-title"><span class="field-content">Seasonal Merchandise Planning to focus on Customer Centricity and Inventory...</span></div>
                            <div class="suggested-url">
                                <a href="http://localhost/articles/customer-centricity-merchandise-planning-and-inventory-optimization/" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="next_arrow" class=""><span><img src="/test/sites/default/files/arrow-next.png"></span></div>   <!-- col-md-1 col-sm-1-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok don't worry. But tell me your description. 

For `Large` size how many columns you want to show?

For `Medium` size how many columns you want to show?
For `Small` size how many columns you want to show?

For `Extra Small` size how many columns you want to show?

Comment: for large screen (1366*768)I want to display 3 column and for mobile view 1 column and for tablet 3 column

Comment: My code is same as you want. 
Follow my code and you get you recommended results.

Comment: No, because the above code correct and have the same columns as you want.

Comment: still I'm getting 1 column in a row

Comment: Yes same issue with me. This is because of the package you are using. 
Wait I do further some changes and will let you know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used another div tag inside the items and added a `column-gap` in the css. Note that this is a minimal representation of the slide. I tried the bootstrap grid layouts but for some reason it does not work inside the carousel. But I suggest that if grid can get work, that is a the best option.

Try the snippet

```css
.carousel{
  background: grey;
}
#myid {
    column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body>
<div id="text-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div id=myid>
                            <p>Sapiente, ducimus, voluptas, mollitia voluptatibus nemo explicabo sit blanditiis laborum dolore illum fuga veniam quae expedita libero accusamus quas harum ex numquam necessitatibus provident deleniti tenetur iusto officiis recusandae corporis culpa quaerat?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div id=myid>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, sint fuga temporibus nam saepe delectus expedita vitae magnam necessitatibus dolores tempore consequatur dicta cumque repellendus eligendi ducimus placeat! </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div id=myid>                           <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/back_pic/03/77/45/0657c00b43e2a66.jpg" width="250px" height="20px;">
                            <p>Sapiente, ducimus, voluptas, mollitia voluptatibus nemo explicabo sit blanditiis laborum dolore illum fuga veniam quae expedita libero accusamus quas harum ex numquam necessitatibus provident deleniti tenetur iusto officiis recusandae corporis culpa quaerat?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

</div>
</body>
```